# How to change the height of an li based on the height of an <a> tag inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list and each of my li items have an border-bottom line to separate the items for better readability. Inside each of my li items, there are some divs and inside each div there is text or a hyperlink. Sometimes the length of the text inside the divs is long in multiple lines and I want to make sure if the text is too long, then the height of my li changes dynamically so the border-bottom of the li separates it from the next one.

This is how my markup looks like:

```
<li class="sfeventListItem">
    <div class="Name">
        <a id="DetailsViewHyperLink1" title="" class="tooltip" href="#">Identification and Classification of Nonconformities in Elastomeric Closures and Aluminum Seals for Parenteral Packaging: Covering Vial Closures, Pre-filled Syringe and Cartridges Components</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

and this is my style:

```
li.sfeventListItem
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    min-height: 30px;
    display: block;
}

li.sfeventListItem .Name a
{

}
```

and this is how my items show up on my website, which is not exactly what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/saVTd.jpg

Comment: Is the `a` floating, absolute, fixed, or anything like that? The `a` currently has no styles, is this right?

Comment: You know what that picture looks like to me? It looks like tabular data. Why not just use a table? That's what they're there for...

Comment: can you post full code??

Comment: Thank you all. I changed display: block to display: inline-block and that fixed it. @tuespetre you are right but I cannot really change that since the code is auto generated by the CMS I am using.

Comment: Ah, nothing like a good pair of tied hands. :( Best of luck to you and your project

Answer (score 0):

Give Li `height: auto`, its height will automatically adjust as per height of its children

```
li
{
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your links a block element and assign top and bottom padding.